# Git will re-add a removed line for no apparent reason

Tags: git

I'm writing a script that picks up the code inside the function in a file like this one:

```
//nextRelease.ts
export default {
  [nextRelease]: ()=>{
    lineToExport();
  }
};
```

and move it to another file with the release version number.

```
//migration7_40_0.ts
export default {
 '7_40_0': ()=>{
   lineToExport();
 }
};
```

Said script runs in a github action each time the beta branch is merged into the staging one, so it also needs to bring those changes back to the `develop` branch, which we accomplish by cherry-picking the last commit on `staging` into `develop`.

The problem arises when new code is added into `nextRelease` before the cherry-picked commit is merged back:

```
//nextRelease.ts@develop
export default {
 [nextRelease]: ()=>{
   lineToExport();
   anotherLineToExport();
 }
};
```

```
//nextRelease.ts@staging
export default {
 [nextRelease]: ()=>{
 }
};
```

The expected output would be:

```
//nextRelease.ts@develop
export default {
  [nextRelease]: ()=>{
    anotherLineToExport();
  }
};
```

But instead, it gets a conflict which can be solved by taking the file like in `develop` (ours) or as in `staging` (theirs), leading to either lost or repeated code.

If I try to run

```
git status SHA | git apply
```

The status clearly show the line deleted:

```
//nextRelease.ts@develop
@@ -2,6 +2,5 @@ export default {
 [nextRelease]: ()=>{
-    lineToExport();
 }
};
```

But because of the context, applying will lead to a fail:

```
error: while searching for:
  export default {
    [nextRelease]: ()=>{
-      lineToExport();
    }
  };
```

So the question is how could I manage to get the moved lines removed while keeping the added ones?

Comment: There will always be a conflict that requires manual resolution when merging two things that touch contiguous lines of code. Here, those two lines are independent, but a similar setup where, say, `lineToExport();` had the opening curly brace of a block. There's so way for Git to know if replacing `lineToExport` by `anotherLineToExport` is safe or not, so it just won't do it.

Comment: Your workflow here only seems safe to me if there are no conflicts at all, so I'm not sure how you could avoid having to merge that commit back before this workflow is invoked. You might have to manually apply it to both branches so it's no longer a conflict when the workflow is triggered?

Comment: Thanks @joanis. The thing is, I cannot pull develop directly into staging because that would jump through the alpha revision.

Comment: By `git status <sha> | git apply` I assume you actually mean `git diff <sha> | git apply`?